# How to transfer selinux file context respectively to the full copy?

Tags: selinux, disk-image

I have an image with files marked with their SELinux context: `system_u:object_r:net_conf_t:s0` for example. I also have a second image with the same files, but without the preserved context (the utility that created this image does not have the ability to preserve the context). How can I apply the file context from the first image to another?

I tried to just copy the files from the first image to the second with context preservation using fsync with the `-X` and `--inplace` option and it worked for some of the files, but then I ran into the error "Not enough space on the device", as I understood, I stumbled to the maximum image size. I also tried to set the `semanage equal` option and after that apply the restorecon command, but unfortunately it didn't work, everything remained in place.

Comment: what kind of image are we talking about?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The origin image is EROFS read only image converted to Ext4 read/write with mke2fs and e2fsdroid tools. The only way to add file context is to specify plat_file_context file with -S option in e2fsdroid but I can't find the way to "export" file context from the origin files. I can mount origin and produced images though.

Comment: but if it's an ext4 image, why would overwriting files lead to full disks? (I don't know e2fsdroid – but what else than a simple `cp --archive`  would you need?)